# Memory Issues with MS SQL Server Backup Jobs

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I will preface this by stating we are using MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

We're having issues when our database backups are running SQL Server takes all of the available memory and never releases. Our current high watermark of memory usage is about 60%. When the backup job runs it goes to 99% and never releases unless we reset the SQL service. This leads me to 2 questions:

1. Dealing with memory allocation, Is there a way to accurately limit memory usage of SQL Server? We are limiting the "Maximum server memory" value to 85% but in consistently exceeds that value.
2. What is the best method of backing up the database? We are currently relying on our provider to maintain the database backups and it seems like the "home grown" method they use through a stored proc and commands is the cause of the memory issues but it is working for other customers of theirs. Should we look at using Maintenance Plans as a replacement?

Any help with this would be great.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to accurately limit memory usage of SQL Server?

Yes there is. [How to: Set a Fixed Amount of Memory (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191144%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> Use the default settings to allow SQL Server to change its memory
>   requirements dynamically based on available system resources. The
>   default setting for min server memory is 0, and the default setting
>   for max server memory is 2147483647 megabytes (MB). The minimum amount
>   of memory you can specify for max server memory is 16 MB.

---

> What is the best method of backing up the database?

You can get the answer here: [Select the Most Optimal Backup Methods for Server](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/12/18/sql-server-select-the-most-optimal-backup-methods-for-server/)